# C++ Functions returnings vs Functions setting a pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

I would like to know the difference between functions that return a value and functions that set a value to a pointer, for example:

***Pointer:***

```
int myVal;
ptr_multiply(5, 5, &myVal);
cout << myVal << endl; //Output: 25
```

***Return:***

```
int myVal = rtn_multiply(5, 5);
cout << myVal << endl; //Output: 25
```

My question focuses in what method to choose when creating functions and why, as well as what advantages/disadvantages can we find in each of them.

Comment: I asked this very question in class at college in the mid-90's.  The prof told me that in general a good rule is to use return if the function doesn't change the state (of the object you're calling the method on or of the program global state itself) and set a pointer (or reference) if it does.  I cannot remember *why* but I do remember him being a expert in formal specification (specifically the Z language), so it may be something to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Readability is the main reason functions typically return what you expect them to return. However, as this is highly subjective, I suggest you strive for consistency within your project.

When you want a function to return multiple things and not group them all together in a structure just so you can return them, an alternative is to return them in output parameters.

Comment: To return multiple things without having to create a struct just for that, you can use std::tuple, which goes well with std::tie

Answer (score 0):

If you have big pieces of data to return, then you might come across to performance-bottlenceks. The reason is that that the returning value must be copied.

But in the most cases you don't have to worry about that, because modern compilers are capable of auto-inline things like that.

Side note: In C++ try to avoid naked pointers as much as possible (use references, smart-pointers)

Comment: RVO comes into play. Also, if you pass an output parameter to a function, don't you have to copy the data into it anyway?

Comment: A strict output parameter would be uninitialized memory, and placement-`new` would be used. Could be pretty fast I think. But basically the same as RVO I guess

Answer (score 0):

One advantage to use the "pointer" method is that you can have multiple "return" values by passing in non-const references or pointers. For example:

```
int output1;
int output2;
get_values("input", &output1, &output2)
```

Comment: You can use `tie` and `tuple` to do that for return values.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a success/failure:

```
int v = -1;
if(ToInt("wibble",&v)){
  // do something with v
}
```

Would fail as "wibble" can't be converted to an int.

The other useful thing is that the function doesn't have to change v:

```
int v = previousValue;
UpdateIfNewValueFound( &v )
```

Comment: You may still use `exception` instead of `bool` to expose failure.

Answer (score 0):

Return the value. With modern compilers there *should* be almost no difference in performance between the two, but returning the value has several advantages:

- By definition, it's what a *function* should do (i.e. a function maps from a domain to a codomain).
- It's self-documenting; if I'm using an unfamiliar API, unless there is good documentation, it can get confusing what is input/output if values are returned in the parameter set. With a returned value there is no ambiguity, and requires less documenting.
- It's easier to use - can half the number of lines needed! Compare

  ```
  int r = f();
  ```

  to

  ```
  int r;
  f(&r);
  ```
- It could make you a better programmer; you have to put more effort into returning multiple values from a function (e.g. via a `struct` or `pair`, as opposed to adding another parameter). If you find you need to do this often, the additional effort may force you to think more carefully about your code design - it's usually better for a function to just do/return one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is stack or heap.

A return-value lies on top of the stack. The pointer-variant lies in heap.

For instance (sensless recursive code to demonstrate return on stack):

```
typedef std::array<int,1000> KByte;
KByte tmp;

KByte f(int nr) {
    if (nr == 1) { tmp[nr]=nr; return tmp; }
    else { tmp[nr]=nr; return f(nr-1); };
}

void f2(int nr, KByte& ret) {
    if (nr == 1) { ret[1]=1; }
    else { ret[nr]=nr; f2( nr-1, ret ); }
};
```

Calling

```
KByte t = f(999); /* Stack error */
```

shoud give you an stack-size error, since 1000 KByte (1GB) on the stack is to much.

Calling

```
KByte t2;
f2( 999, t2 );
```

should work without stack problem. (It also uses recursion depth 1000, but does not lie the return value on the stack.